# How to play rest file in INtelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I run the *.rest* file in the IntelliJ community edition?
[image]

Comment: This is an Ultimate edition feature and you can't use it in the Community edition. You may try the Ultimate edition which has 30 days trial. Also, the IDEA provides a feature that could covert these into curl commands so you could use these curl commands without Ultimate edition later: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html#http-to-curl

Comment: Also you can use HTTP Client CLI. It's free, but you have to run it from console (not GUI in IDE): https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2022/12/http-client-cli-run-requests-and-tests-on-ci/. It's workaround if you don't have Ultimate Edition.